# Suddenly getting "Unable to get Lros Token." when running Powershell commands

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, microsoft-teams

So I've been using Powershell for a while with our Microsoft 365 environment with no major issues.

I'm specifically using the SkypeOnlineConnector to manage our Teams Direct Routing environment.

Today, suddenly out of no where, I've been encountering the following error when running the Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy and Grant-CsTenantDialPlan commands:

```
PS C:\Users\shvlzz> Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity $upn -PolicyName $null

Unable to get Lros Token.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=495c9e16-e17...au1001,DC=local:OCSADUserOrAppContact) [Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy], LrosClie 
   ntErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GrantPolicy,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Xds.GrantOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicyCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminau1.online.lync.com



PS C:\Users\shvlzz> Grant-CsTenantDialPlan -identity $upn -PolicyName $null

Unable to get Lros Token.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=495c9e16-e17...au1001,DC=local:OCSADUserOrAppContact) [Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy], LrosClie 
   ntErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GrantPolicy,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Xds.GrantOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicyCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminau1.online.lync.com
```

I've tried with a real PolicyName and it also fails with same error:

```
PS C:\Users\shvlzz> Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity $upn -PolicyName "NZ-Unrestricted"
Unable to get Lros Token.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=495c9e16-e17...au1001,DC=local:OCSADUserOrAppContact) [Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy], LrosClie 
   ntErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GrantPolicy,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Xds.GrantOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicyCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminau1.online.lync.com
```

I've tried terminating and reestablishing the SkypeOnlineConnector session but the issue still occurs.

Get and Set commands are working properly.

I don't know what the error means so I can't properly troubleshoot to fix it.

I have tried Googling "Lros Token" but have come up emtpy. Even Google doesn't seem to know what it is.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. I've raised a ticket with Microsoft support and waiting to see what they say.

I can confirm I was able to do the same changes via Admin Center and works as expected.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have any explanation of what you did to solve the issue. Please edit and add details of what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Happens for me also.
We've seen this across 9 Office 365 tenants.
We cannot grant CsClientPolicy, TeamsCallingPolicy, OnlineVoiceroutingPolicy.
E.g. Set-CsUser -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled works fine.

I'm filing a ticket with MS now.

Comment: MS confirms that they can reproduce the issue.
It has been escalated to the Teams Product Group.

Comment: There is an advisory from Microsoft: TM224973:
"Admins can't make changes to voice routing or calling policies in Microsoft Teams admin center or PowerShell"

Comment: where are you seeing the advisory? I can't see it in our 365 portal (Service Health -> Advisories and History)

Comment: I saw it in our 365 portal. It has been marked as "resolved", but I can still reproduce the error in at least 3 different tenants.

Comment: Weird, I still can't see any advisory in our 365 portal. However, the issue has since disappeared without explanation.